# Variable not being stored in the code when sheet changes

Tags: vba, excel, variables, with-statement

I'm quite new to coding and have encountered a probably very trivial issue. When I run the code line by line in the 'Trade_Sheet' tab, the variable Date_range is picked up correctly as a date previously copied, and updated for 7 days later. However the problem comes when I run the macro in the main tab 'Share_Calc_Tab' where the macro is situated. If I do so, it seems like the variable Date_range sets to 0, and while the rest of the operation is performed, the date will be missing.

The code is below:

```
Sub Audit_Trade()

    Dim Trade_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Share_Calc_Tab As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Date_range As Date

    Set Trade_Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Trades")
    Set Share_Calc_Tab = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("End Share Calc (ESC) GLOBAL")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Trade_Sheet

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Date_range = Cells(lastrow, 1).Offset(-27, 0).Value
        Cells(lastrow + 2, 1).Value = Date_range + 7

    End With

    Share_Calc_Tab.Activate
    Range("Trade_Instruction_Daily").Copy
    Trade_Sheet.Activate
    Cells(lastrow + 3, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Share_Calc_Tab.Activate
    Range("B22").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: If either of the answers helped you please consider [accepting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting an answer rewards the contributor and helps those that follow you to find a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not define the worksheet correctly. See the points(dots) here:

```
With Trade_Sheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Date_range = .Cells(lastrow, 1).Offset(-27, 0).Value
    .Cells(lastrow + 2, 1).Value = Date_range + 7
End With
```

In your code, you are missing 2 of them:
[image]

Thus, the `Cells()` refers to the `ActiveSheet`, and not to the `Trade_Sheet`. In general, `Activate` and `Select` are considered a bad practice in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), thus it is a good idea avoid them:

- [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

---

*For what is worth, this is probably the most common error in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), thus you can be proud of yourself for reaching it. I guess that almost every VBA person has experienced it at least once.*

Comment: Thank you so much! Loved the explanation.

Comment: @JohnyL - you can consider yourself lucky. This is probably the most common error in [tag:vba]. See it again here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469103/data-going-to-wrong-workbook

Comment: Oh... This is such a common error... I used to read [great book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Excel-2007-VBA-Programmer-s-Reference.productCd-0470046430.html) which explains this very moment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps problem is you did not have dots in this part of code?

```
 lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 Date_range = .Cells(lastrow, 1).Offset(-27, 0).Value
 .Cells(lastrow + 2, 1).Value = Date_range + 7
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed! Concise and effective.