# Copying data from one worksheet to another work sheet is not working

Tags: excel, vba

What I Have:
I am copying data to one workbook sheet data in another workbook sheet following VBA code I did write When I run this its showing Application-defined error.

```
Workbooks(mainworkbook).Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").Value = Workbooks(dataworkbook).Sheets(ws.Name).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(clearrow, lcol1)).Value
```

Comment: If you do it that way I think you will have to `.Resize` the target range to the size of the source range. `Copy` does not require that.

Comment: Any other alternate way to import that one workbook sheet data into another without using copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

The cells are not fully qualified. See the added dots, they make a huge difference:

```
With Workbooks(dataworkbook).Sheets(ws.Name)
    Workbooks(mainworkbook).Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").Value = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(clearrow, lcol1)).Value
End With
```

Similar issues:

- [Stepping through yields different result then just running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061169/stepping-through-yields-different-result-then-just-running/53061292#53061292)
- [Variable not being stored in the code when sheet changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465500/variable-not-being-stored-in-the-code-when-sheet-changes)